# Refresh activity without open again?

Tags: java, android

I have button for for install apk file download from server in specific folder and user some time delete apk file from folder but this button do not disable in same time but should exit activity and open again  ... my question is how refresh status button after delete file apk by user without open activity again

```
 Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install_font);
        final File file_1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
        if(file_1.exists()){
            install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+"app-debug.apk")),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });

        }else {
            install_font.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
```

and i try add onResume but disable button all time mean if apk file exists the button is disable and apk file not exists the button is disable

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
        final Button install_font = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install_font);
        install_font.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your file exist every time the user enter to the application , then set the enabled flag based on it.
Try this code:

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
    final Button install_font = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install_font);
    install_font.setEnabled(file.exists());
}
```

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: if your file doesn't exist every time the user enter to your app again, the button will be disabled.  what is the problem? are you sure you delete the file?

Comment: could you explain better?

Comment: problem after add @Override public void onResume() { super.onResume(); the button all time disable if file exist or doesn't exist

Comment: did you check my code?  install_font.setEnabled(file.exists());

Comment: did you press home and enter again to your app? how are you testing? describe the flow